# Google App Script and public locks

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that I have a `doGet()` a `doPost()` as well as a timed trigger to do some updates. I want these to block each other. Yay the LockService... hopefully.

The Google documentation on the [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) does not document the `getPublicLock()` method and I can't seem to find anything specific to my needs. The documentation above does say that `getDocumentLock()` will return `null` in a web app which is not particularly useful, and general posts around the interweb suggest that it will stop bits of code being run concurrently... which isn't quite what I want. What I want is to stop requests for data when data is being updated.

I have tried to test it, but I can't seem to get a script to run for suitably long enough to test this to my satisfaction.

If I use:

```
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000);
```

In all 3 entry points, will the script successfully lock when any other invocation is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not run into LockService.getPublicLock() in Google-Apps-Script.

However the LockService.getScriptLock() should work. As the documentation states :

> Gets a lock that prevents any user from concurrently running a section of code. A code section guarded by a script lock cannot be executed simultaneously regardless of the identity of the user. Note that the lock is not actually acquired until Lock.tryLock(timeoutInMillis) or Lock.waitLock(timeoutInMillis) is called.

I have used it particularly with Web App and as far as I have tested it it works as promised:

While anyone using the app has reserved a single Script Lock in the script, any other block locked by  Script Lock will not execute, for any user.

I would have added this as a comment but I have no right to comment yet..

Comment: A code section guarded by a script lock cannot be executed simultaneously - I don't want that. I don't want any code to run, not a section.

Comment: Oh I see. Correct me if I am wrong but would that not be solved by using something like this:

function doGet(e)
{
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  var success = lock.tryLock(10000);
 if (!success) {
   return;
 }
}

And since it formats badly: 
Cannot you just start doGet and doPost by trying to acquire the lock and return if it is reserved -> that way any user cannot request data while it is being updated.

Comment: That's the basis of my question also :) The documentation says it blocks a section of code. doGet() and doPost() are separate bits of code. I could write a common lock function that all input points call, that returns the lock for release later, but if the script blocks as I need then there is no need for that.

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry for having troubles to understand your question. I think it is quite clear now :)

Comment: Sorry for pressing enter too quick too.. :)

So the Script Lock blocks every bit of code locked by the Script Lock in the current script ( If that I cannot sound more stupid). 

So yes, all the App Script Lock (to my knowledge ) block just sections, so basically you just call the lock at the very beginning of the code, but that way you can block it all anyhow.  :)